# How to test whether two time ranges overlap?

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, range

I need to implement booking functionality and ensure that bookings don't overlap in a Rails app.

The `cover?` and `between?` methods aren't quite what I need. I have to ensure uniqueness of a time range when compared to other potential ranges on the same model, and do it efficiently.

I THINK it can be done using [`overlaps?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Range.html#method-i-overlaps-3F). The problem is that this returns TRUE for something like this:

```
(1..5).overlaps?(5..9)
=> true
```

If I compared a booking that ended right when another started (`3:30 - 4:00` versus `4:00 - 4:30`), it would say they do overlap, but they technically don't. That would be a problem right?

[ValidatesOverlap](https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap) seems to handle the issue, including edge overlap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about checking whether one of the ranges covers either endpoint of the other range?

Comment: Need to convert it into a Time object with *miliseconds* included.. I think

Comment: Found this gem: https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap, seems to handle the issue in rails including overlapping edges.

Answer (score 11):

```
def overlap?(x,y)
  (x.first - y.end) * (y.first - x.end) > 0
end
```

will work. The problem is that `Interval` uses `>=`, as you can see in "[Test if two date ranges overlap in Ruby or Rails](http://makandracards.com/makandra/984-test-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-ruby-or-rails)".

Comment: The other trick doesn't work because floating points are weird. :) `irb(main):048:0> (1..5-2*Float::EPSILON).overlaps?(5..9)
=> true
irb(main):049:0> (1..5-3*Float::EPSILON).overlaps?(5..9)
=> false`

Comment: That should probably be `(x.first - y.end) * (y.first - x.end) >= 0` otherwise a date will not overlap itself.

Comment: @Johnny No, OP specifically asked for a case where a date doesn't overlap itself.

Answer (score 6):

For your scenario, why do we have to include end time? After all, booking is finished at that time and slot is available from that time onwards. So below should make sense.

`(1...5).overlaps?(5...9)`

Comment: This should be the top answer here. This did the trick for me.