# Check if an hour range is contained in another hour range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a start time and an end time. I want to check if this hour range is contained in the hour ranges defined in my model.

For example, I have a `start_time="12:30"` and an `end_time="13:30"`.

My model includes 2 objects with this time definition:

> Object1 have start="12:00" and end="13:00"
>
> Object2 have start="13:00" and end="14:00"

I want to create a `select` with a comparison that should match both Object1 and Object2 given the start_time and end_time defined above.

This is my sample code:

```
Model.all.select(|object| (object.start<=start_time and object.end<=end_time)
```

This sample code just select the objects that include the given time range in the object time range.

I want to cover all the cases is there a ruby methods that check if a time range is partially containend in another one.

Comment: “I want to create a select”—feel free to do so.

Comment: added my sample code just looking for a smart way to implement it without writing all the possible cases

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
Model.where(
  "(TIME :start_time, TIME :end_time) OVERLAPS (start, end)",
  start_time: "12:30",
  end_time: "13:30"
)
```

Also, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22639669/1155142